# how to create and use a print method using java

Tags: java

Based on the code below, I need to modify the code in the Employee class by creating a specialised print method called employee print() and show how it will be used to print in the employee Test class! Any help please? Here is the code:

```
class Employee1{
      String empName;
      String empNum;
      String empEmailAddress;
      int yearOfBirth;
}


public class employeeTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee1 emp1 = new Employee1();
    emp1.empName = "Sam";
    emp1.empNum = "213-23-978";
    emp1.empEmailAddress = "sammy@company.za";



    Employee1 emp2 = new Employee1();
    emp2.empName = "Tasha";
    emp2.empNum = "315-90-274";
    emp2.yearOfBirth = 1982;

    System.out.println("Employee Name: " + emp1.empName);
    System.out.println("Employee Number: " + emp1.empNum);
    System.out.println("Email Adress: " + emp1.empEmailAddress);
    System.out.println("Year of Birth: " + emp1.yearOfBirth);

    System.out.println("Employee Name: " + emp2.empName);
    System.out.println("Employee Number: " + emp2.empNum);
    System.out.println("Email Address: " + emp2.empEmailAddress);
    System.out.println("Year of Birth: " + emp2.yearOfBirth);
}
```

}

Comment: You should really show us what you've tried first.

Comment: Yes you are right brother,but it was a long road and i came up with this code!it was not given to me like that,i went through all steps to came up with that but i wasn't able to implement that last method!thank you for your comment brother!

Answer (score 1):

You add a method called print to the employee class called print

```
class Employee1{
      String empName;
      String empNum;
      String empEmailAddress;
      int yearOfBirth;

      public void print() {
          System.out.println("Employee name:" + empName);
          System.out.println("Employee number:" + empNum);
          // etc
      }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
// these lines replace the System.out.println block in your code
emp1.print();
emp2.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee1
{
  String empName;
  String empNum;
  String empEmailAddress;
  int yearOfBirth;
  @Override toString(){
    System.out.println(empName + empNum + empEmailAddress + yearOfBirth);
  }
}

emp.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override toString() method in class Employee like this

```
class Employee1{
  String empName;
  String empNum;
  String empEmailAddress;
  int yearOfBirth;
@Override
public String toString(){
return empName + emNum +.....
}
}
```

And use this to print in EmployeeTest `sysout(instanceOfEmployee)`